# Injecting key combinations into Bash tty using TIOCSTI in Python

Tags: bash, key, combinations, tty, ioctl

I am trying to inject key combinations (like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) into a tty using the TIOCSTI in Python.

For some key combinations I have found the corresponding hex code for Bash shells using the following [table](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm) which works good.

From this table I can see that for example <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is `'\x01'` etc.

```
import sys,os,Queue
import termios,fcntl
# replace xx with a tty num
tty_name = "/dev/pts/xx";
parent_fd = os.open(tty_name, os.O_RDWR)

special_char = "Ctrl_a"

if special_char == "Ctrl_a":
   send_char = '\x01'
if special_char == "Ctrl_e":
   send_char = '\x05'
if special_char == "Ctrl_c":
   send_char = '\x03'

fcntl.ioctl(self.parent_fd, termios.TIOCSTI, send_char)
```

But how can I get the hex codes for other combinations such as
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>  etc. I need a full list or a way how to get this information for any possible combo as I want to implement most bash shortcuts for moving, manipulating the history etc. to inject.

Or is there any other way to inject key-combinations using TIOCSTI ?

As I can only send single chars to a tty I wonder if there is anything else possible.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The usual working of "control codes" is that the "control" modifier substracts 64 from the character code.

"A" is ASCII character 65, so "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>" is "65-64=1".
Is it enough for you to extend this scheme to your situation?

So, if you need the control code for, for example, "`Device Control 4`" (ASCII code 20), you'd add 64, to obtain "84", which is "T".
Therefore, the control-code for `DC4` would be "<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>".
In the reverse direction, the value for "<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>" (history search in BASH) is R-64, so 82-64=18 (Device Control 2)

[ASCIItable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/) can help with a complete listing of all character codes in ASCII

**Update**: Since you were asking specifically for "<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>":
The 'Control mean minus 64" doesn't apply to Alt, unfortunately; that seems to be handled completely differently, by the keyboard driver, by generating "key codes" (also called "scancodes", variably written with or without spaces) that don't necessarily map to ASCII. (Keycodes just *happen* to map to ASCII for 0-9 and A-Z, which leads to much confusion)

[This page](http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html) lists some more keycodes, including "155" for "<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>"